# remote SSH device to communicate with devices on a local network

Tags: ssh, lan, remote-access, local

I have a question regarding networking. So I have a device on a completely different network that I can SSH into with my laptop. I want the device to communicate with some other devices locally on my laptop's network. What is the standard procedure for this? I thought about using my laptop as a sort of network switch and simply forward all of its ports to my device that I ssh into

Edit: I am looking for a way to connect the remote device fully to the network of my laptop, as if it was connected to the same network. E.G. I can broadcast ARP who-is packages with it on that network.

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525217/create-network-interface-from-ssh-tunnel/525262#525262) on the unix stackexchange. Basically you can use ssh as a VPN, with virtual network interfaces at each end.

Comment: I think this answers it! Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

Depends really on what constituents 'communicate'. If the machines on your local LAN need to communicate with already known unarbitrary ports, you can use SSH forwarding and have your laptop act as a proxy.

From each box within your LAN:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 laptop ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 -N remotemachine
```

The LAN machine(s) would then be able to reach remote machine on `127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was thinking of something like this as well. However, I want the device to be completely connected to the network of my laptop, as if it was connected to the same network. (Using the IP and MAC of my laptop probably). E.G. being able to broadcast ARP who-is packages. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: There is no need for more than one SSH connection. SSH is able to tunnel multiple ports over one connection. It is also sufficient if one machine connects to the remote device and then exposes the forwarded ports to the other machine on the LAN (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can forward the device's ports to your local machine using SSH's `-L` option:

```
ssh -N -L 0.0.0.0:<Forwarded Port>:localhost:<Forwarded Port> <Device IP>
```

(Repeat `-L` option to forward more than one port)

All other machine on your LAN will then be able to use the service by connecting to your laptop on the `<Forwarded Port>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was thinking about this as well. However, I was more looking for a way to connect the remote device fully to the network of my laptop, as if it was connected to the same network. E.G. I can broadcast ARP who-is packages with it on that network. Do you know a way to do this as well?

Comment: You could set up a VPN to integrate the remote device into your LAN. However, this requires the remote device to run a VPN client and comes with some overhead (computational, bandwith, power consumption, memory consumption). An IOT device will probably not have sufficient resources.

Comment: Good idea, I'll look into it! Maybe there is a lightweight VPN client, openVPN sounds pretty okay

Comment: Like I said: it really depends on the involved devices. For a Linux environment, Wireguard would be a good choice. In an heterogeneous environtment OpenVPN will probably be your best bet.